# Display value form nested ng-repeat option in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I need display option chosen from select which is in table where columns and row are generated dynamically and in the second table I want do background color cell will be in this color which was choose in first table, but I don't know to get articleItem.not_mixed_colors.rgb and use in second table?

My code:

```
  <table class="table-bordered table-condensed table-select" ng-class="[{'add-colors-table': pyNumber >= 24 }]">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber" ng-class="[{'border': $index+1 == divOne }, {'border': $index+1 == divTwo }, {'border': $index+1 == divThree }]" >{{$index+1}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="articleItem in articleColors">
            <td ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber" ng-class="[{'border': $index+1 == divOne }, {'border': $index+1 == divTwo }, {'border': $index+1 == divThree }]"  class="select-td">  
                <select id="articleColorsData" name="py{{$index+1}}" class="form-control" ng-model="articleColorsData.kolory[$index]" ng-init="articleColorsData.kolory[$index] = 'x'">
                    <option ng-value="x"  value="x">x</option>
                    <option tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="{{ oneColor }}" ng-repeat="oneColor in articleItem.all_colors" ng-value="x"  value="{{ oneColor }}" ng-model="oneColor">{{ oneColor }}</option>
                </select>  
            </td>                                          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="articleItem in articleColors">
            <td width="58" ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber" ng-class="[{'border': $index+1 == divOne }, {'border': $index+1 == divTwo }, {'border': $index+1 == divThree }]"  class="select-td">  
                <div id="articleColorsData" name="py{{$index+1}}" class="form-control" tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip="{{articleColorsData.kolory[$index]}}">
                    {{articleColorsData.kolory[$index]}}
                </div>  
            </td>                                          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Extra info:

-selected color are saved to database as $scope.articleColorsData,

-rangeFilter() - filter which generate columns,

-articleColors data below:

```
[{
            "id_art": "2084",
            "id_rys": "311",
            "nazwa_art": "nowy",
            "kolory_pod": "Y,M",
            "pantony": "P1777,P179,P188,P1905,P1795",
            "kolory_art": "Y,M,M50+Y100,P1777,P179,P188,P1905,P1795",
            "all_colors": ["Y", "M", "M50+Y100", "P1777", "P179", "P188", "P1905", "P1795"],
            "not_mixed_colors": [{
                "color_name": "Y",
                "rgb": "255,255,0"
            }, {
                "color_name": "M",
                "rgb": "255,0,255"
            }, {
                "color_name": "P1777",
                "rgb": "255,107,163"
            }, {
                "color_name": "P179",
                "rgb": "255,31,23"
            }, {
                "color_name": "P188",
                "rgb": "103,6,48"
            }, {
                "color_name": "P1905",
                "rgb": "255,138,240"
            }, {
                "color_name": "P1795",
                "rgb": "255,8,31"
            }]
        }]
```

[Edit] 
All Controller code:

```
appPokayoke.controller('CreateArticleColorsCtr', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', 'articles', '$location', 'articlesOfDrawings', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, articles, $location, articlesOfDrawings, rangeFilter ) {


        var drawingId = $routeParams.drawingId;
        var pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;
        var articleName = $routeParams.articleName;
        var divOne = $routeParams.divOne;
        var divTwo = $routeParams.divTwo;
        var divThree = $routeParams.divThree;

        $scope.filterBy = {};

        $scope.pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;

        var divOne = $routeParams.divOne;
        $scope.divOne = divOne; 

        var divTwo = $routeParams.divTwo;
        $scope.divTwo = divTwo; 

        var divThree = $routeParams.divThree;
        $scope.divThree = divThree; 

        $scope.articleColors = {};
        $scope.articleColorsData = {
        "id_rys" : drawingId, 
        "ile_py" : pyNumber, 
        "nazwa_art" : articleName,

        };

        articles.getNewArticle(
            $routeParams.articleName, 
            $routeParams.drawingId,
            function (data) {
                if(data !== '') {
                    $scope.articleColors = data;
                    console.log('articlecolors:');
                    console.log($scope.articleColors);

                }
                else {
                    console.log('not ok articleColors');  
                }
            }
        );

        // tabelka z dodanymi już artykułami
        articlesOfDrawings.getArticlesOfDrawings(
            $routeParams.pyNumber, 
            $routeParams.drawingId,
            function (data) {
                console.log("getArticlesOfDrawings data:" + data + "/");
                if(data !== '') {
                    $scope.articlesOfDrawings = data;
                    console.log('articlesOfDrawings:');  
                    console.log($scope.articlesOfDrawings); 
                }
                else {

                    console.log('not ok articlesOfDrawings');  
                }
            }
        );


        $scope.saveArticleColors = function (articleColorsData, success) {

            success = success || function() {};

            $http.post('api/admin/articles/save_colors/', {articleColorsData:articleColorsData})
            .success(function (errors, data){ 
                if ( errors) {
                    $scope.errors = errors; 
                    console.log($scope.errors);
                }
                else {
                    success(data.articleColorsData);
                    $scope.articleColorsData = articleColorsData;
                    console.log("Save article: "+ $scope.articleColorsData);
                    $location.path('/admin/drawings/'+ drawingId + '/' + pyNumber +'/' + divOne +'/' + divTwo +'/' + divThree);
                }

            }).error(function (){
                console.log('Problem ArticleColors');
            });

        }

    }]);
```

Comment: Please include your 'controller' code.

Comment: @JustinRusso I edited question and added controller.